# Gradle - configure the output file name of the profile report

Tags: gradle

When running a Gradle build with the  `--profile` option enabled, the profile report is written to the `build/reports/profile` folder, and the main HTML file name is `profile-$YY-$MM-$DD-$TIME`.

I would like to change the main HTML file name to simply `index.html`, so that publishing on Jenkins is easier.

How can I do that? (I think by configuring something in the Gradle build file? I couldn't find any reference in the docs)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, no, there is no way to do that with the existing options.
The `--profile` gets handled by `ReportGeneratingProfileListener` there you can clearly see the function `buildFinished`

```
public void buildFinished(BuildProfile buildProfile) {
    ProfileReportRenderer renderer = new ProfileReportRenderer();
    File file = new File(buildDir, "reports/profile/profile-" + FILE_DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date(buildProfile.getBuildStarted())) + ".html");
    renderer.writeTo(buildProfile, file);
    renderReportUrl(file);
}
```

That naming pattern is hardcoded in the HTML file generation.

You can add a listener of your own and implement `buildFinished` to rename that file but you have no gurentees about the order in which these listeners will be executed, thus your listener can run before the `ReportGeneratingProfileListener` is executed.

The simplest and fastest solution will be to rename by pattern right after you Gradle command in your Jenkins job
something along the lines of `mv profile-*.html index.html`